# Rewriting from MonoTouch Application to MonoDroid

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android

I'm going to rewrite the application from Monotouh to Monodroid application for android. Correct me if I'm wrong. The logic remains the same as in MonoTouch or change anything? If something changes, please tell me, what?

As far as I understand, only GIU changes. Thanks in advance!

So, this is my code where i call data from my server:

```
namespace Mobile{
public static class SiteHelper
{
    public static string DbPath = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Sql_1.4.sqlite");
    public const string TempDbPath = "./Sql.sqlite";


    public static UIView View { get; set; }

    public static BaseController Controller { get; set; }

    private static event NIHandler _noInternetHandler;

    private static bool _noInternetShoved = false;
    public static string SiteDomain = "http://mysite.com"; //files which connecting to the DB on server (.asx files)

    private delegate void NIHandler ();



    public static XDocument DoRequest (string Request)
    {

        if (_noInternetHandler != null) {
            foreach (var del in _noInternetHandler.GetInvocationList()) {
                _noInternetHandler -= del as NIHandler;
            }
        }

        if (Controller != null)
            _noInternetHandler += new NIHandler (Controller.PushThenNoInternet);

        string CryptoString = "";
        string Language = "ru";

        using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create()) {
            string hashKey = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ().Substring (0, 4);
            CryptoString = Request + (Request.Contains ("?") ? "&" : "?") + "hash=" + GetMd5Hash (
                md5Hash,
                "myprogMobhash_" + hashKey
            ) + "&hashKey=" + hashKey + "&language=" + Language;




            UIActivityIndicatorView _preloader = null;

            if (Controller != null) {
                Controller.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate() {
                    _preloader = new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray);


                    if (View != null && Request.IndexOf ("login.ashx") == -1 
                        && Request.IndexOf ("yandex") == -1 
                        && Request.IndexOf ("GetDialogMessages") == -1) {

                        lock (_preloader) {
                            if (_preloader != null && !_preloader.IsAnimating)
                                _preloader.HidesWhenStopped = true;
                            _preloader.Frame = new RectangleF (150, 170, 30, 30);
                            _preloader.Transform = MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.MakeScale ((float)1.3, (float)1.3);
                            _preloader.StartAnimating ();
                            View.Add (_preloader);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


            /*ctx.GetText(Resource.String.SiteAddress)*/
            Stream Stream = null;
            try {
                HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest (new Uri (SiteDomain + "/FolderWithFiles/" + CryptoString));
                request.Timeout = 8000;
                Stream = request.GetResponse ().GetResponseStream ();
                _noInternetShoved = false;
                if (_noInternetHandler != null)
                    _noInternetHandler -= new NIHandler (Controller.PushThenNoInternet);
            } catch (WebException) {
                if (_noInternetHandler != null)
                    _noInternetHandler.Invoke ();
                var resp = new XDocument (new XElement ("Response", 
                            new XElement ("status", "error"), 
                            new XElement ("error", "Отсутствует интернет"))
                );
                return resp;

            }


            StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader (Stream);
            string Resp = Sr.ReadToEnd ();
            XDocument Response = XDocument.Parse (Resp.Substring (0, Resp.IndexOf ("<html>") == -1 ? Resp.Length : Resp.IndexOf ("<!DOCTYPE html>")));
            string Hash = Response.Descendants ().Where (x => x.Name == "hash")
                .FirstOrDefault ().Value;
            string HashKey = Response.Descendants ().Where (x => x.Name == "hashKey")
                .FirstOrDefault ().Value;

            Sr.Close ();
            Stream.Close ();


            if (Controller != null && _preloader != null) {
                Controller.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate() {
                    lock (_preloader) {
                        _preloader.StopAnimating ();
                        _preloader.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                    }
                });
            }


            if (VerifyMd5Hash (
                md5Hash,
                "mobileSitehash_" + HashKey,
                Hash
            ))
                return Response;
            else
                throw new Exception ();


        }
    }



    public static XDocument DoWriteFileRequest (string Request, byte[] file)
    {
        string CryptoString = "";
        string Language = "ru";

        using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create()) {
            string hashKey = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ().Substring (0, 4);
            CryptoString = Request + (Request.Contains ("?") ? "&" : "?") + "hash=" + GetMd5Hash (
                md5Hash,
                "mobileMobhash_" + hashKey
            ) + "&hashKey=" + hashKey + "&language=" + Language;

            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (SiteDomain + "/misc/mobile/" + CryptoString);
            Req.Method = "POST"; 
            Stream requestStream = Req.GetRequestStream ();
            requestStream.Write (file, 0, file.Length);
            requestStream.Close ();

            Stream Stream = Req.GetResponse ().GetResponseStream ();
            StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader (Stream);
            string Resp = Sr.ReadToEnd ();
            XDocument Response = XDocument.Parse (Resp);
            string Hash = Response.Descendants ().Where (x => x.Name == "hash")
                .FirstOrDefault ().Value;
            string HashKey = Response.Descendants ().Where (x => x.Name == "hashKey")
                .FirstOrDefault ().Value;

            Sr.Close ();
            Stream.Close ();

            if (VerifyMd5Hash (
                md5Hash,
                "mobileSitehash_" + HashKey,
                Hash
            ))
                return Response;
            else
                throw new Exception ();


        }
    }

    public static string GetMd5Hash (MD5 md5Hash, string input)
    {

        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder ();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
            sBuilder.Append (data [i].ToString ("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.2
        return sBuilder.ToString ();
    }

    //Geting the info for my app
    public static List<PackageListModel> GetUserPackages (int UserID)
    {
        List<PackageListModel> Events = new List<PackageListModel> ();
        string Req = "SomeFile.ashx?UserID=" + UserID;
        XDocument XmlAnswer = DoRequest (Req);

        if (XmlAnswer.Descendants ("status").First ().Value == "ok") {
            foreach (var el in XmlAnswer.Descendants ("Response").First ().Descendants().Where(x=>x.Name == "Event")) {
                PackageListModel Event = null;
                Event = new PackageListModel ()
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(el.Attribute("ID").Value),
                    Title = el.Element("Title").Value,
                    Date = el.Element("Date").Value,
                    Price = el.Element("Price").Value,
                    ImageUrl = el.Element("ImageUrl").Value,
                    Location = el.Element("Location").Value
                };
                Events.Add (Event);
            }
        }
        return Events;
    }

    //Получить пользовательские поездки
    public static List<TransporterListModel> GetUserTransporters (int UserID)
    {
        List<TransporterListModel> Events = new List<TransporterListModel> ();
        string Req = "SomeFile.ashx?UserID=" + UserID;
        XDocument XmlAnswer = DoRequest (Req);

        if (XmlAnswer.Descendants ("status").First ().Value == "ok") {
            foreach (var el in XmlAnswer.Descendants ("Response").First ().Descendants().Where(x=>x.Name == "Event")) {
                TransporterListModel Event = null;
                Event = new TransporterListModel ()
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(el.Attribute("ID").Value),
                    Date = el.Element("Date").Value,
                    Price = el.Element("Price").Value,
                    TransportsStr = el.Element("Transports").Value,
                    Location = el.Element("Location").Value
                };
                Events.Add (Event);
            }
        }
        return Events;

    }

            }
}
```

}

Comment: you should definitely post some code examples, show what you already tried and post concrete problems in order to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder whether it makes sense in it. Can I do that? I'm using SQLite database and get information from the server in the form of xml. I want to know globally if i can to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should read [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Building_Cross_Platform_Applications).
In brief - you can reuse application logic that not depends on platform-specific parts, so working with database/server can be shared between MonoTouch and Mono for Android.

Comment: Cool!)) Thank you. I think that I can do, what i'm going to.